# How to set a maximum zoom limit for Apple's Large Image Downsizing iOS example?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, zooming

I'm using Apple's Large Image Downsizing example code in my project to load large images that can be zoomed.

The sample project can be downloaded here: [Apple Large Image Downsizing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011173-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

The UIScrollView source can be viewed directly here:
[ImageScrollView.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Listings/LargeImageDownsizing_ImageScrollView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011173-LargeImageDownsizing_ImageScrollView_m-DontLinkElementID_4)

It works well, apart from the fact that the user can zoom-in till infinity. It seems that while Apple is using the UIScrollView's zoom functionality the actual zooming is performed by rescaling the source image and not by transforming a UIView. (though my understanding of how it works is a bit flaky!)

I'm looking for the maximum zoom to be limited to the full resolution of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I was unaware of that project, but it would seem to not do what you really want. It lets you take a very large image file and downsize it.

There is github project [PhotoScrollerNetwork](https://github.com/dhoerl/PhotoScrollerNetwork) that lets you download huge JPEG images (one is a NASA 18,000 x 18,000) and decodes them incrementally as they arrive. It then uses CATiledLayers to display the image at a reduction small enough to fit on the window, but can zoom out to the full image resolution. This might be more in line with your objective.

The project is based on Apple's PhotoScroller project, which only works with pre-tiled images.

EDIT: I downloaded the Large Image Downsizing project. It has much in common with Apple's [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html), and if you poke around the later project you can probably figure out how to limit the zooming. I suspect it has to do with these lines:

```
    self.maximumZoomScale = 5.0f;
    self.minimumZoomScale = 0.25f;
```

That said, I took the leaves image and stuck it into PhotoScrollerNetwork's bundle and did a comparison on an iPhone 4. The Large Image Downsizing project took one minute to decode the image, and you get to see an incremental view of the image while it render, but it (I believe) it requires the whole image on disk before you can proceed.

PhotoScrollerNetwork was able to decode the image in 32 seconds - just about half the time. If you download from the network, it will decode the image as it receives the data, so the delay from the last chunk of data and when you see the image is small.

PhotoScrollerNetwork Offers:

- concurrent image downloads and rendering
- levels of detail automatically set to optimize showing image at full size and all-on-one-screen
- very smooth zooming and panning (due to pre-rendered tiles)
- no files are saved on disk (but it uses the disk cache): this means if the app crashes no cleanup required.

  The log messages below:

  2012-09-05 11:46:11.784 LargeImage[2242:3107] beginning downsize. iterations: 14, tile height: 754.000000, remainder height: 425
  2012-09-05 11:46:11.788 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 1 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:13.132 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 2 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:15.148 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 3 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:17.526 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 4 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:20.627 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 5 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:24.017 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 6 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:27.696 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 7 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:31.823 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 8 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:36.638 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 9 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:41.791 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 10 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:47.309 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 11 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:53.299 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 12 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:46:59.832 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 13 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:47:06.800 LargeImage[2242:3107] iteration 14 of 14
  2012-09-05 11:47:13.666 LargeImage[2242:3107] downsize complete.

  2012-09-05 11:57:24.465 PhotoScrollerNetworkTurbo[2262:1c03] Initialize:   total: 270237696 used: 163041280 FREE: 107196416   [resident=6574080 virtual=346882048]
  2012-09-05 11:57:24.532 PhotoScrollerNetworkTurbo[2262:1c03] ORIENTATION=1 string=1
  2012-09-05 11:57:24.535 PhotoScrollerNetworkTurbo[2262:1c03] ZLEVELS=5
  2012-09-05 11:57:57.463 PhotoScrollerNetworkTurbo[2262:1c03] FINISH-I: 32974 milliseconds
  2012-09-05 11:57:57.946 PhotoScrollerNetworkTurbo[2262:1c03] FINISHED:   total: 260521984 used: 219987968 FREE: 40534016   [resident=3469312 virtual=349683712]

Comment: The Large Image Downsizing project takes a single large image and decodes it incrementally using CATiledLayers and does not require the image be chopped up first.

Comment: Thing is my application requires that a single image be stored locally  within the app. I'm basically building an offline map of sorts. The image file is very high resolution so it ends up being 49MB when uncompressed by iOS which was crashing devices due to spike in Live memory usage. Using LID project ment that I could decode the image in small chunks (tiles) and it does everything I want apart from let me set maximum zoom level. The `self.maximumZoomScale` does not seem to limit the image resizing, just limits the resizing of the rect of the image view.

Comment: Just having a look at `PhotoScrollerNetwork` sounds promising.

Comment: I noticed that LID sets levelsOfDetailBias, which is a kind of extra magnification (PSN sets it to 1 or 0). If you look a PS and compare / contrast with LID you probably can fix this one issue. Also, with PhotoScroller, there are utilities to pre-tile your images, so just the tiles are in your bundle, and that would be really fast for your users - no wait time what so ever.

Comment: I can't get PhotoScrollerNetwork to work it just crashes every time I run with an EXC_BAD_EXCEPTION.